# set session with javascript read with asp.net

Tags: javascript, session

How can I write a session with javascript and read it with asp.net (vb).

I already tried this to write (js):

```
sessionStorage.setItem("vsh", hash);
```

And

```
 checkout.Sender.Hash = Session("vsh").ToString
```

But it returns a reference error, as if there was no session.

Comment: session storage != asp.net session.

Comment: Server-side sessions are persisted completely differently than client-side sessions are. In order for one to use data from another, you will have to manually extract the data and move it into the other repository.